# How can I break lines automatically in tabular in IEEEtran?

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx, ieeetran

I use `tabularx` to break lines automatically in tabular. Here is my code.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Term}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Description}} \\
\hline
key1 & A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

It works in `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` but fails in `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` (two columns). Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: your very long text is not realy long

Comment: @touhami there are 8 copies of `A very long text.` but it only shows 5 copies.

Comment: Ok sorry but for me it works well with10

Comment: your class IEEE use twocolumn so it's better to use table* environment so and don't use [h] option

Comment: @touhami Now, the table occupies two columns. How can I make it occupy one columns with automatic line-break?

Comment: use `\linewidth` rather than `\textwidth`

Comment: @SparkandShine, you select `textwidth' for width of table. In two colummarticle (anyone) this is width of two column. Use `\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|l|X|}` instead \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}` should sove your problem (if I correctly understand them).

Comment: @Zarko It does work. BTW, use `\begin{table}` instead of `\begin{table*}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple: replace `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`. I took the opportunity to improve the vertical spacing of the rows of the table, and to propose a solution without vertical rules, that looks better, in the opinion of many:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, tabularx, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{A table}
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Term}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Description}} \\
    \hline
    key1 & A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2-5]
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{A table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
    \toprule
    \thead{Term} & \thead{Description} \\
    \midrule
    key1 & A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From a coding point of view, it might be even clearer to use `\columnwidth`, rather than `\linewidth`.

Comment: @Mico: Surely, but coding `\inewidth` works in all circumstances (poly and monostyles), όχι;

Answer (score 2):

You can get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\caption{A table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Term}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Description}} \\
\hline \hline
key1 & A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[3-8]
\end{document}
```

Use `tabularx` to be able to utilize all of the available width. First column is set to `l` since it is short, the other is set using `X` to automatically break within the remaining available width. `\linewidth` is not equal to `\textwidth` use the first in two-column documents.

NOTE: You could've used `booktabs` since it is more beautiful, but, the style I used is most common in IEEE journals and conferences.